# Qt3D rotations and translations

Tags: qt3d

I am new to Qt3D and I am wondering if it is possible to take an entity and rotate it around an axis eg. x-axis.  Then translate it in a certain direction and then rotate it around the origin.

All I can do is one rotation and translation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Transform object:

```
Transform {
    id: transform
    scale3D: Qt.vector3d(root.scaleX, root.scaleY, root.scaleZ);
    rotation: fromEulerAngles(rotateX, rotateY, rotateZ);
    translation: Qt.vector3d(root.x, root.y, root.z);
}
```

Using Transform, you can scale, rotate, translate your entity. See Qt3D help or examples for more informations.